# Check 2 differents status with Karate

Tags: karate

I have a question about the framework Karate.
I would like to know if we can check 2 status with karate.

For example :
Given url myUrl
When method get
Then status 200 or 204

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
Then assert responseStatus == 200 || responseStatus == 204
```

EDIT: also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65938884/143475

Comment: Thanks for your answer Peter. Your framework is great !

Comment: @Chris I had a JS logic mistake in my answer, just edited it.

Comment: Thanks! Works fine.