# How to use if condition in Karate for dynamic responseCodes

Tags: dsl, karate

I am trying to run few tests which needs "`Delete.feature`" file to be called at of the end of each scenario if it is successful but if it's a failure tests then it should not call "`Delete.feature`" file.

My test look something like this :

```
Given url ApiAdminURL

And path AdminPath

And header apigateway-apikey = apiGatewayKey

And header apigateway-basepath = 'lambdaTest'

* json myReq = read('users.json')

* set myReq.apiConf.subscriptionTiers = subscriptionTiers

* print 'my subscriptions : ', myReq.apiConf

And request myReq 

When method post

Then status responseCode

* call read('Delete.feature')

Examples:

| subscriptionTiers                     |responseCode|               
| [Unlimited,Gold,Bronze, Silver]       |200         |
| [Unlimited,Gold,Bronze]               |200         |
| [Unlimited,Gold,BronzeAuto-Approved]  |400         |
```

If the response code is `200`, then it should run the command  "`* call read('Delete.feature')`" and if the `responseCode` is `400`, then it should skip this command.

can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic

```
Then assert responseStatus == 200 || responseStatus == 400
And if (responseStatus == 400) karate.call('delete.feature')
```

One additional comment, `Then status responseCode` - I don't think that will work.

EDIT - also see: [Check 2 differents status with Karate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50952243/143475)

Comment: it was a typo. I am sorry i passed  it as "Then status <responseCode>" and it works like that.