# Can I use the status shortcut in Karate to check a response class instead of just one code

Tags: karate

I am using Karate to test other people's implementations of an API. When checking response status codes I often need to accept more than one response. For example in response to a PUT I may see 200, 201, 205 - they are equally valid. I know I can use

```
Then assert responseStatus >= 200 && responseStatus < 300
```

to check for success but the shortcut really helps readability of the tests.

Would you consider an enhancement to the language to support response classes such as:

- success (meaning 200-299)
- redirect (meaning 300-399)
- fail (meaning 400-499)
- 2xx
- 3xx
- 4xx

If I were to look at submitting a PR for this would you agree it is useful and would you have a preferred mechanism? Would these classes be best as parsed symbols or strings that force a different match to be implemented when it detects the status is not a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, my first reaction is not to add a new keyword. Also to be honest, this seems to be a rare requirement - never had this ask before, I guess API testing would generally mean predictable responses.

My proposal is that you can write a custom function:

```
* def statusSuccess = function(){ var status = karate.get('responseStatus'); return status >= 200 && status < 300 }

* url 'https://httpbin.org'
* path 'status', 200
* method get
* assert statusSuccess()
```

EDIT - also see this: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1364433453412851714

Comment: Thanks - that is a cleaner solution than the one I had.
FYI - there was a similar question at least once before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952243/check-2-differents-status-with-karate but I can see it is a rare case.