# How to handle multiple conditions for responseStatus

Tags: karate

I am making an API call that can result in a 200, 204, 404, or a 417. The only responseStatus that I cannot accept is a 417. The API is designed in a way where if it hits a 417, it keeps retrying until it gets a different status (200, 204, or a 404).

To fulfill this condition, I wrote up the following:

```
        When method GET
        And retry until match [200, 204, 404] contains responseStatus
```

However, when the API responds with a 417, the test just stops right there. It doesn't retry. Am I handling this incorrectly?

Please advise.

Comment: also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65938884/143475